# program to resize image?

Tags: images

I'm looking for an image editor that I can use to do a wide array of resizing tasks including canvas size (expand/contract the image canvas), image size (enlarge/shrink the entire image), and cropping. So far, all I can find are cropping tools in the apps I'm finding, but I want the others as well. Does anyone know of any apps that provide all three tools?

Answer (score 2):

Just a part-answer: i'm using a nice app for resizing images: [Image Shrink](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.anolivetree) (there's also a [lite version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.anolivetree.imageshrinklite)).

It works via the share intent - you "share" an image to it, the app does its job and the result can be shared again (e.g. if you want to send a large image via mail and want to resize it first, easily done with that app).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tablet, Adobe have just released a whole suite of [tablet focussed (paid) apps](http://www.adobe.com/products/touchapps.html), including [Photoshop Touch](https://market.android.com/details?id=air.com.adobe.pstouch).

Whilst I haven't tried it out yet, it does look like it should be able to do resizing tasks, I can definitely see a "Resize" menu option in one of the screenshots on the [Features page](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-touch/features.html).